# how to remove object from array element in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using Javascript. I have a set of data I need to remove the object based on element value. Here I have attached my code. In my code I have month element. I need to remove the object when month is `1`. How to do this?

```
var Data=[ 
    { "State": "PA", "DispenseMonth": "1/1/2017" }, 
    { "State": "MS", "DispenseMonth": "1/1/2017" }, 
    { "State": "CT", "DispenseMonth": "1/1/2017" }, 
    { "State": "TX", "DispenseMonth": "2/1/2017"}, 
    { "State": "DE", "DispenseMonth": "2/1/2017"}, 
    { "State": "TN", "DispenseMonth": "2/1/2017" }, 
    { "State": "FL", "DispenseMonth": "3/1/2017" }, 
    { "State": "SD", "DispenseMonth": "4/1/2017" }, 
    { "State": "GA", "DispenseMonth": "5/1/2017"}, 
    { "State": "SC", "DispenseMonth": "6/1/2017"}, 
    { "State": "IA", "DispenseMonth": "7/1/2017" }, 
    { "State": "RI", "DispenseMonth": "8/1/2017" }, 
    { "State": "ID", "DispenseMonth": "9/1/2017"}
] 

Data.forEach(item => {
     return item.Month = item.DispenseMonth.split('/')[0];
});
console.log(Data);
```

---

Code I tried:

```
 for(i = 0; i < MainStateData.length; i++) {
    var bjMonth = MainStateData[i].Month;
    if (bjMonth == 1) {
        delete MainStateData[bjMonth]; 
        MainStateData.splice([i]);
        delete MainStateData[i];
    }     
}
```

Comment: Reverse `for` loop and `splice` when condition satisfies.

Comment: Is the date format `m/d/yyyy`?

Comment: yes m/d/yyyy @Tushar

Comment: i tired splice  not woking correctly i think so @Tushar

Comment: kindly recorrect my code @Jaromanda

Comment: `[n]` is for accessing items in an Array or Object. `MainStateData.splice([i])` should be `MainStateData.splice(i, 1)` (you forgot the length). The `delete` is for Objects only and won't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can go thorough your array in reverse and check for month

```
var month = '1';

for(var i = Data.length - 1; i > -1 ; i-- ){
   //date format dd/m/yyyy             
   if(Data[i].DispenseMonth.split('/')[1] == month)
       Date.splice(i, 1);
}
```

Comment: It should be `[0]`, the format of date is [`m/d/yyyy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44149449/how-to-remove-object-from-array-element-in-javascript/44149552#comment75315971_44149449)

Comment: in the data object its look like dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 2):

Try `Data.filter(obj => obj["DispenseMonth"].split('/')[0] !== '1')`
The filter method loops through the Data array and calls the function `obj => obj["DispenseMonth"].split('/')[0] !== '1'` on every object.  If the callback returns true, it keeps the item in array.

`Data = Data.filter(obj => obj["DispenseMonth"].split('/')[0] !== '1')` will effectively delete the object from the array.

Comment: @Stephen L no filter i need  to remove that object no need filter

Comment: my need is i have one textbox when i click number i need to that particular month from array

Answer (score 2):

First find the index of the element/object that you want to remove.

For example, let's say you want to remove 2nd element(0-indexed)

```
var array = ["Apple", "Mango", "Grapes", "Bread"];
var grape = array.splice(2, 1);
```

```js
var Data = [{
    "State": "PA",
    "DispenseMonth": "1/1/2017"
  },
  {
    "State": "MS",
    "DispenseMonth": "1/1/2017"
  },
  {
    "State": "CT",
    "DispenseMonth": "1/1/2017"
  },
  {
    "State": "TX",
    "DispenseMonth": "2/1/2017"
  },
  {
    "State": "DE",
    "DispenseMonth": "2/1/2017"
  },
  {
    "State": "TN",
    "DispenseMonth": "2/1/2017"
  },
  {
    "State": "FL",
    "DispenseMonth": "3/1/2017"
  },
  {
    "State": "SD",
    "DispenseMonth": "4/1/2017"
  },
  {
    "State": "GA",
    "DispenseMonth": "5/1/2017"
  },
  {
    "State": "SC",
    "DispenseMonth": "6/1/2017"
  },
  {
    "State": "IA",
    "DispenseMonth": "7/1/2017"
  },
  {
    "State": "RI",
    "DispenseMonth": "8/1/2017"
  },
  {
    "State": "ID",
    "DispenseMonth": "9/1/2017"
  }
];

Data.forEach(function(item) {
  return item.Month = parseInt(item.DispenseMonth.split('/')[0], 10);
});

console.log("Array Length Before Deletion: ", Data.length);
// Option 1: Both works
 for (i =  Data.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  var bjMonth = Data[i].Month;
  if (bjMonth === 1) {
    console.log("Deleted: ", Data[i].State);
    Data.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
// Option 2: Both works
/*Data = Data.filter(function(item, index) {
  return item.Month > 1
});*/
console.log("Array Length After Deletion: ", Data.length);
```

Reference to the docs: [MDN Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: Not relevant to question. OP wants to remove objects from the array whose index is not known beforehand. Also, OP is aware of how `splice` works.

Comment: I don't think he does.  See `MainStateData.splice ([i]);` above.

Comment: i just try that way @Stephen L

Comment: Try Data.splice(i, 1) as @azad mentioned in one of the answers.  Beware though, if you click multiple months you can't get them back!

Answer (score 2):

You can use reverse `for` loop with `splice` to remove the items from array.

```
for (var i = Data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (Data[i].DispenseMonth.split('/')[0] === '1') {
        Data.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

```js
var Data = [{
    "State": "PA",
    "DispenseMonth": "1/1/2017"
  }, {
    "State": "MS",
    "DispenseMonth": "1/1/2017"
  }, {
    "State": "CT",
    "DispenseMonth": "1/1/2017"
  },
  {
    "State": "TX",
    "DispenseMonth": "2/1/2017"
  },
  {
    "State": "DE",
    "DispenseMonth": "2/1/2017"
  },
  {
    "State": "TN",
    "DispenseMonth": "2/1/2017"
  },
  {
    "State": "FL",
    "DispenseMonth": "3/1/2017"
  },
  {
    "State": "SD",
    "DispenseMonth": "4/1/2017"
  },
  {
    "State": "GA",
    "DispenseMonth": "5/1/2017"
  },
  {
    "State": "SC",
    "DispenseMonth": "6/1/2017"
  },
  {
    "State": "IA",
    "DispenseMonth": "7/1/2017"
  },
  {
    "State": "RI",
    "DispenseMonth": "8/1/2017"
  },
  {
    "State": "ID",
    "DispenseMonth": "9/1/2017"
  }
];

for (var i = Data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (Data[i].DispenseMonth.split('/')[0] === '1') {
    Data.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
console.log(Data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=control) method:

```
var newArray = Data.filter(function(value){
  return value.DispenseMonth.split('/')[0]!=1;
});

// this will give the array which do not contain objects with month=1
console.log(newArray);
```

Hope this helps.